# Systemd unit fails to start after restart of server

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer

I have a rather strange situation where an unit fails to start after a restart of the server. To me the issue seems to be caused by the fact that SystemD tries to stop (!) the service before it starts it. This fails because of the restart the process isn't there.
To make this even more strange this does not happen at every reboot.

I guess there is either a setting I missed or a mistake I made and that at least the first effect can be solved by fixing my unit file:

This is the output of `systemctl status`:

```
 foo.service - Foo service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/foo.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-10-11 07:58:52 UTC; 57min ago
  Process: 1113 ExecStop=/bin/kill -TERM $MAINPID (code=exited, status=217/USER)
  Process: 1035 ExecStart=/var/opt/jdk8/bin/java -Dprocess_name=foo -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/opt/temp/foo -jar /var/opt/foo/foo.jar --spring.config.location=file:///var/opt/foo/config/application.yml (code=exited, status=217/USER)
 Main PID: 1035 (code=exited, status=217/USER)
```

My unit file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
        Description = Foo service
        After = syslog.target
[Service]
        User = somebody
        ExecStart = /var/opt/jdk8/bin/java -Dprocess_name=foo -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/opt/temp/foo -jar /var/opt/foo/foo.jar --spring.config.location=file:///var/opt/foo/config/application.yml
        SuccessExitStatus = 143
        ExecStop = /bin/kill -TERM $MAINPID
        TimeoutSec = 300
        StandardError = journal
        SyslogIdentifier = foo
[Install]
        WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

Could this problem be worked around by setting up a timer file or will this only make the error happen over and over again ?

Most of the time the services run fine when the server restarts but sometimes they fail. Whenever I start them manually with `systemctl start ...` they work fine too.
I have 10 services with nearly identical setup (they only use a different `.jar`), they all suffer from the same problem. Even my prometheus unit fails so it can't be only a Java<->systemd problem.

I checked the logs and saw several entries like these (from different units):

```
Oct 11 07:58:51 server systemd[996]: Failed at step USER spawning /var/opt/jdk8/bin/java: No such process
Oct 11 07:58:51 server systemd[997]: Failed at step USER spawning /var/opt/prometheus/node_exporter: No such process
Oct 11 07:58:51 server systemd[1]: bar.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=217/USER
```

Comment: We would need some logs to figure out why your process did not start in the first place. Sounds like it could be relying on some dependency (a service, network, filesystem, .. whatever) that is missing when first starting. If you can figure out what's that missing dependency, you should be able to configure your systemd unit file accordingly.

Comment: @SYN `journalctl -u foo --since ...` should do the job or do I need to skip a filter ?

Comment: might do the job, indeed, assuming that error is being logged somewhere. Worst case scenario, I'ld go with: reboot your machine. When in grub, type "e" to edit your boot entry. In the params passed to your kernel, add `init=/bin/sh`. Boot from that, you should end up with a shell, without any service started/systemd off. Then, start your application from the command line (su as somebody, execute the ExecStart command). If there's a dependency missing, it should crash, and may include some additional error not logged in journald.

Comment: @SYN I checked the logs and updated my question, please have a look. Unfortunately I can't make use of the grub trick because all these servers are virtual server and not under my control. I can do `sudo su` but don't have any access to the console before Linux was brought up